# unable to run filezilla

Tags: filezilla, libtiff

When I run `filezilla` , this output is shown:

```
filezilla: error while loading shared libraries: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtiff.so.5: invalid ELF header
```

And here is the `ll /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ | grep libtiff` output:

```
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root       16 may 29 14:23 libtiff.so.5 -> libtiff.so.5.2.4
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   475496 may 29 14:23 libtiff.so.5.2.4
```

And when I try `sudo apt install --reinstall libtiff5` this output is show:

```
/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtiff.so.5 is not an ELF file - it has the wrong magic bytes at the start.
```

Uninstall and install filezilla no have any effect,
any idea to fix it?

Result of `lsb_release -a`

```
LSB Version:    core-9.20160110ubuntu0.2-amd64:core-9.20160110ubuntu0.2-noarch:security-9.20160110ubuntu0.2-amd64:security-9.20160110ubuntu0.2-noarch
Distributor ID: LinuxMint
Description:    Linux Mint 18.1 Serena
Release:        18.1
Codename:       serena
```

Result of `uname -a`

```
Linux gabriel-B85-HD3 4.4.0-59-generic #80-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 6 17:47:47 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: How did you install Filezilla?

Comment: sudo apt-get install filezilla

Comment: Please add this command output to your post `ll /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ | grep libtiff`

Comment: Which version and flavour of Ubuntu are you running? From which iso file did you install it? What is the output of the following commands, `lsb_release -a` and `uname -a`

Comment: It is Linux Mint and it is an old kernel, 4.4.0-59-generic #80. In the same series and Ubuntu 16.04 (the Xenial kernel) I have 4.4-78-generic #99. Maybe also other components of your system are not up to date. Have you tried `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` and reboot? If general tips do not help, I think you should ask for more specific advice at the Linux Mint forum.

Comment: @sudodus it was very bad idea, now i dont have any boot option, only mem test in grub(

Comment: I am very sorry. Those commands are very reliable in Ubuntu, and I did not expect that they would break your Linux MInt. Ob

Comment: I tried Mint some year ago, and I *think* I used the common command line tools including `apt-get` which  comes from Debian. It should be possible to repair the system for example by using *Boot Repair*. But it is **safest to ask at the Mint Forum**, where you can get help for your particular version and flavour of the installed system.

Comment: I made a fresh installation of Linux Mint 18.1 Serena from the iso file `linuxmint-18.1-cinnamon-64bit.iso` into a test computer, and directly afterwards (without making all installed program packages up to date) I ran the following commands to install filezilla: `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get install filezilla`. It worked, and now I can use filezilla. I will test, if I can break this system with `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` ...

Comment: After running `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` (looking successful, no complaints), I still have the same kernel as in the iso file, 4.4.0-53-generic #74. This is not the same kernel as you were using. How did you get your system upgraded to the kernel  `4.4.0-59-generic #80`? Filezilla is still working (before reboot and after reboot). So I did not break the system, it is still working like it should after `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`

Comment: Finally, I was able to select manually (override the safe setting for the kernel upgrade) and install the same version of the linux kernel that I have in my Ubuntu, `4.4.0-78-generic #99`, and it works too. Linux Mint boots correctly, and Filezilla works with this kernel running too. So I suspect that your system was somehow damaged already before you ran those command lines. And that is the reason, that you could not install Filezilla. **I would recommend, that you make a fresh installation** (like I did in order to test things). It is likely to work, because it works for me.

Comment: Thank you very much for the work done.
I'm beginning to suspect that the case is in the broken sectors of hdd.
Yes, this idea visited me, with the need to run the system to make buckup of all stuff