# Filezilla not starting at all

Tags: 18.04, filezilla

I am on Ubuntu 18.04.01 LTS on an old machine running Sandybridge i5 with 4 GB ram. After an update (and I havent run any updates for filezilla), the program has just stopped working.

I have followed all steps from this thread to try and revive, but nothing worked

[unable to run filezilla](https://askubuntu.com/questions/921036/unable-to-run-filezilla)

I did a full remove and purge of filezilla and after that installed the latest from the Ubuntu Software library (version 3.28), and started filezilla from the terminal. (Please see picture attached for the errors)

[image: error on restarting filezilla]

> $ filezilla
>      filezilla: symbol lookup error: filezilla: undefined symbol: _ZN2fz6buffer3addEm

Any help and guidance will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Output of other commands as follows:

> $ which filezilla
>      /usr/bin/filezilla
>
> $ ldd $(which filezilla)
>      linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffea5d9a000)
>      libfilezilla.so.0 => /usr/local/lib/libfilezilla.so.0 (0x00007fc834bab000)
>      libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fc83498c000)
>      libpugixml.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpugixml.so.1 (0x00007fc834755000)
>      libnettle.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnettle.so.6 (0x00007fc83451f000)
>      libhogweed.so.4 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhogweed.so.4 (0x00007fc8342eb000)
>      libgnutls.so.30 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so.30 (0x00007fc833f86000)
>      libdbus-1.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdbus-1.so.3 (0x00007fc833d39000) 
>      libwx_gtk2u_aui-3.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwx_gtk2u_aui-3.0.so.0 (0x00007fc833aa6000)
>      libwx_gtk2u_xrc-3.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwx_gtk2u_xrc-3.0.so.0 (0x00007fc8337b1000)
>      libwx_gtk2u_adv-3.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwx_gtk2u_adv-3.0.so.0 (0x00007fc8333d9000)
>      libwx_gtk2u_core-3.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwx_gtk2u_core-3.0.so.0 (0x00007fc832ba7000)
>      libwx_baseu-3.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwx_baseu-3.0.so.0 (0x00007fc832718000)
>      libsqlite3.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.so.0 (0x00007fc83240f000)
>      libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0 (0x00007fc83215a000)
>      libgobject-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0 (0x00007fc831f06000)
>      libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fc831b78000)
>      libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fc831960000)
>      libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fc83156f000)
>      /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fc835568000)
>      libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fc8311d1000)
>      libgmp.so.10 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmp.so.10 (0x00007fc830f50000)
>      libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007fc830d33000)
>      libp11-kit.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libp11-kit.so.0 (0x00007fc830a04000)
>      libidn2.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libidn2.so.0 (0x00007fc8307e7000)
>      libunistring.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libunistring.so.2 (0x00007fc830469000)
>      libtasn1.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtasn1.so.6 (0x00007fc830256000)
>      libsystemd.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsystemd.so.0 (0x00007fc82ffd2000)
>      libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0 (0x00007fc82f990000)
>      libwx_gtk2u_html-3.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwx_gtk2u_html-3.0.so.0 (0x00007fc82f6bd000)
>      libwx_baseu_xml-3.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwx_baseu_xml-3.0.so.0 (0x00007fc82f4ad000)
>      libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0 (0x00007fc82f289000)
>      libpango-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpango-1.0.so.0 (0x00007fc82f03c000)>>
>      libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0x00007fc82e9ee000)
>      libnotify.so.4 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnotify.so.4 (0x00007fc82e7e6000)
>      libpangocairo-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpangocairo-1.0.so.0 (0x00007fc82e5d9000)
>      libcairo.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcairo.so.2 (0x00007fc82e2bc000)
>      libXxf86vm.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXxf86vm.so.1 (0x00007fc82e0b6000)
>      libSM.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSM.so.6 (0x00007fc82deae000)
>      libpng16.so.16 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng16.so.16 (0x00007fc82dc7c000)
>      libjpeg.so.8 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.8 (0x00007fc82da14000)
>      libtiff.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtiff.so.5 (0x00007fc82d79d000)
>      libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fc82d599000)
>      libgio-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0 (0x00007fc82d1fb000)
>      libfontconfig.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfontconfig.so.1 (0x00007fc82cfb6000)
>      libXrender.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXrender.so.1 (0x00007fc82cdac000)
>      libXinerama.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXinerama.so.1 (0x00007fc82cba9000)
>      libXi.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXi.so.6 (0x00007fc82c999000)
>      libXrandr.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXrandr.so.2 (0x00007fc82c78e000)
>      libXcursor.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXcursor.so.1 (0x00007fc82c584000)
>      libXcomposite.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXcomposite.so.1 (0x00007fc82c381000)
>      libXdamage.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdamage.so.1 (0x00007fc82c17e000)
>      libXfixes.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXfixes.so.3 (0x00007fc82bf78000)
>      libXext.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6 (0x00007fc82bd66000)
>      libffi.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6 (0x00007fc82bb5e000)
>      librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007fc82b956000)
>      liblzma.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5 (0x00007fc82b730000)
>      liblz4.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblz4.so.1 (0x00007fc82b514000)
>      libgcrypt.so.20 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcrypt.so.20 (0x00007fc82b1f9000)
>      libgmodule-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmodule-2.0.so.0 (0x00007fc82aff5000)
>      libatk-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libatk-1.0.so.0 (0x00007fc82adcf000)
>      libpangoft2-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpangoft2-1.0.so.0 (0x00007fc82abb9000)
>      libexpat.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1 (0x00007fc82a987000)
>      libthai.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthai.so.0 (0x00007fc82a77e000)
>      libpcre.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0x00007fc82a50c000)
>      libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0x00007fc82a2e4000)
>      libfreetype.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6 (0x00007fc82a030000)
>      libpixman-1.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpixman-1.so.0 (0x00007fc829d8b000)
>      libxcb-shm.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-shm.so.0 (0x00007fc829b88000)
>      libxcb-render.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-render.so.0 (0x00007fc82997b000)
>      libICE.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libICE.so.6 (0x00007fc829760000)
>      libuuid.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuuid.so.1 (0x00007fc829559000)
>      libjbig.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjbig.so.0 (0x00007fc82934b000)
>      libselinux.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1 (0x00007fc829123000)
>      libresolv.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2 (0x00007fc828f08000)
>      libmount.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmount.so.1 (0x00007fc828cb4000)
>      libgpg-error.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgpg-error.so.0 (0x00007fc828a9f000)
>      libharfbuzz.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libharfbuzz.so.0 (0x00007fc828801000)
>      libdatrie.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdatrie.so.1 (0x00007fc8285fa000)
>      libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0x00007fc8283f6000)
>      libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0x00007fc8281f0000)
>      libbsd.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbsd.so.0 (0x00007fc827fdb000)
>      libblkid.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libblkid.so.1 (0x00007fc827d8e000)
>      libgraphite2.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgraphite2.so.3 (0x00007fc827b61000)
>
> $ apt-cache policy filezilla filezilla-common libfilezilla0
>      filezilla:
>      Installed: 3.28.0-1
>      Candidate: 3.28.0-1
>      Version table:
>      *** 3.28.0-1 500
>          500 http://ubuntu.ipserverone.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
>          100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
>
> filezilla-common:
>      Installed: 3.28.0-1
>      Candidate: 3.28.0-1
>      Version table:
>      *** 3.28.0-1 500
>        500 http://ubuntu.ipserverone.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
>        500 http://ubuntu.ipserverone.com/ubuntu bionic/universe i386 Packages
>        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
>
> libfilezilla0:
>      Installed: 0.11.0-1
>      Candidate: 0.11.0-1
>      Version table:
>      *** 0.11.0-1 500
>        500 http://ubuntu.ipserverone.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
>        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

Comment: Please try to start YOUR `filezilla` on YOUR Ubuntu and add its terminal output to the question. Linking to other questions is not useful.

Comment: Hi N0rbert - the second link has the picture of my terminal window, but pasting the error below for easy reference. 

PCSB16FG:~$ filezilla
filezilla: symbol lookup error: filezilla: undefined symbol: _ZN2fz6buffer3addEm

Thanks

Comment: Then please add output of `which filezilla`, `ldd $(which filezilla)` and `apt-cache policy filezilla filezilla-common libfilezilla0` to the question.

Comment: Done Sir - added to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ldd` output has one strange line:

```
$ ldd $(which filezilla)
...
libfilezilla.so.0 => /usr/local/lib/libfilezilla.so.0 (0x00007fc834bab000)
...
```

(it seems that you have installed filezilla from source before).

But correct line is:

```
libfilezilla.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfilezilla.so.0
```

So to fix the issue your should remove the problematic library manually:

```
sudo rm /usr/local/lib/libfilezilla.so.0*
```

and reinstall correct one from deb-package:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libfilezilla0
```