# Cannot start FileZilla (Bus Error)

Tags: server, ftp, filezilla

I am a Ubuntu 20.04LTS and recently installed FileZilla via apt-get to access files from a remote server. Whenever I run `filezilla` on the terminal, I get the following output:

`Bus error (core dumped)`

I tried reinstalling the package but it doesn't work. Unlike the issue pointed [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/798031/cannot-start-filezilla), there is no config file at `/home/asr/.config/filezilla/`.  I have also appended the output when FileZilla is run as mentioned in this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1073279/filezilla-not-starting-at-all).

```
$ filezilla
Bus error (core dumped)

$ which filezilla
/usr/bin/filezilla

$ apt-cache policy filezilla filezilla-common libfilezilla0
filezilla:
  Installed: 3.46.3-1build1
  Candidate: 3.46.3-1build1
  Version table:
 *** 3.46.3-1build1 500
        500 http://ftp.iitm.ac.in/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
filezilla-common:
  Installed: 3.46.3-1build1
  Candidate: 3.46.3-1build1
  Version table:
 *** 3.46.3-1build1 500
        500 http://ftp.iitm.ac.in/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://ftp.iitm.ac.in/ubuntu focal/universe i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libfilezilla0:
  Installed: 0.19.3-1build1
  Candidate: 0.19.3-1build1
  Version table:
 *** 0.19.3-1build1 500
        500 http://ftp.iitm.ac.in/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

$ ldd $(which filezilla)
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fff0ffd1000)
    libfilezilla.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfilezilla.so.3 (0x00007fcf823ad000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fcf8238a000)
    libpugixml.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpugixml.so.1 (0x00007fcf8234a000)
    libdbus-1.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdbus-1.so.3 (0x00007fcf822f9000)
    libwx_gtk3u_aui-3.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwx_gtk3u_aui-3.0.so.0 (0x00007fcf8225a000)
    libwx_gtk3u_xrc-3.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwx_gtk3u_xrc-3.0.so.0 (0x00007fcf8214f000)
    libwx_gtk3u_adv-3.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwx_gtk3u_adv-3.0.so.0 (0x00007fcf81f60000)
    libwx_gtk3u_core-3.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwx_gtk3u_core-3.0.so.0 (0x00007fcf818dc000)
    libwx_baseu-3.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwx_baseu-3.0.so.0 (0x00007fcf81618000)
    libsqlite3.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.so.0 (0x00007fcf814ef000)
    libgtk-3.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0 (0x00007fcf80d3e000)
    libgdk-3.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdk-3.so.0 (0x00007fcf80c39000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fcf80a55000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fcf80a3a000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fcf80848000)
    libnettle.so.7 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnettle.so.7 (0x00007fcf8080e000)
    libhogweed.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhogweed.so.5 (0x00007fcf807d7000)
    libgnutls.so.30 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so.30 (0x00007fcf80601000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fcf82a36000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fcf804b0000)
    libsystemd.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsystemd.so.0 (0x00007fcf80401000)
    libgobject-2.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0 (0x00007fcf803a1000)
    libwx_gtk3u_html-3.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwx_gtk3u_html-3.0.so.0 (0x00007fcf802bf000)
    libwx_baseu_xml-3.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwx_baseu_xml-3.0.so.0 (0x00007fcf802ac000)
    libpango-1.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpango-1.0.so.0 (0x00007fcf8025b000)
    libcairo.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcairo.so.2 (0x00007fcf80138000)
    libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0 (0x00007fcf80110000)
    libglib-2.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0x00007fcf7ffe7000)
    libX11.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0x00007fcf7feaa000)
    libnotify.so.4 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnotify.so.4 (0x00007fcf7fe9f000)
    libpangocairo-1.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpangocairo-1.0.so.0 (0x00007fcf7fe8b000)
    libSM.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSM.so.6 (0x00007fcf7fe80000)
    libpng16.so.16 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng16.so.16 (0x00007fcf7fe48000)
    libjpeg.so.8 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.8 (0x00007fcf7fdc3000)
    libtiff.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtiff.so.5 (0x00007fcf7fd42000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007fcf7fd26000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fcf7fd1e000)
    libgmodule-2.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmodule-2.0.so.0 (0x00007fcf7fd18000)
    libXi.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXi.so.6 (0x00007fcf7fd06000)
    libXfixes.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXfixes.so.3 (0x00007fcf7fcfe000)
    libcairo-gobject.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcairo-gobject.so.2 (0x00007fcf7fcf2000)
    libatk-1.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libatk-1.0.so.0 (0x00007fcf7fcc8000)
    libatk-bridge-2.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libatk-bridge-2.0.so.0 (0x00007fcf7fc8f000)
    libepoxy.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libepoxy.so.0 (0x00007fcf7fb5c000)
    libfribidi.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfribidi.so.0 (0x00007fcf7fb3f000)
    libgio-2.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0 (0x00007fcf7f95e000)
    libpangoft2-1.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpangoft2-1.0.so.0 (0x00007fcf7f945000)
    libharfbuzz.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libharfbuzz.so.0 (0x00007fcf7f841000)
    libfontconfig.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfontconfig.so.1 (0x00007fcf7f7f8000)
    libfreetype.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6 (0x00007fcf7f739000)
    libXinerama.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXinerama.so.1 (0x00007fcf7f734000)
    libXrandr.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXrandr.so.2 (0x00007fcf7f727000)
    libXcursor.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXcursor.so.1 (0x00007fcf7f71a000)
    libXcomposite.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXcomposite.so.1 (0x00007fcf7f713000)
    libXdamage.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdamage.so.1 (0x00007fcf7f70e000)
    libxkbcommon.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxkbcommon.so.0 (0x00007fcf7f6cc000)
    libwayland-cursor.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwayland-cursor.so.0 (0x00007fcf7f6c1000)
    libwayland-egl.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwayland-egl.so.1 (0x00007fcf7f6bc000)
    libwayland-client.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwayland-client.so.0 (0x00007fcf7f6ab000)
    libXext.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6 (0x00007fcf7f696000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007fcf7f68a000)
    libgmp.so.10 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmp.so.10 (0x00007fcf7f606000)
    libp11-kit.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libp11-kit.so.0 (0x00007fcf7f4d0000)
    libidn2.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libidn2.so.0 (0x00007fcf7f4af000)
    libunistring.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libunistring.so.2 (0x00007fcf7f32d000)
    libtasn1.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtasn1.so.6 (0x00007fcf7f315000)
    liblzma.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5 (0x00007fcf7f2ec000)
    liblz4.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblz4.so.1 (0x00007fcf7f2cb000)
    libgcrypt.so.20 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcrypt.so.20 (0x00007fcf7f1ad000)
    libffi.so.7 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.7 (0x00007fcf7f1a1000)
    libexpat.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1 (0x00007fcf7f171000)
    libthai.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthai.so.0 (0x00007fcf7f166000)
    libpixman-1.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpixman-1.so.0 (0x00007fcf7f0bf000)
    libxcb-shm.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-shm.so.0 (0x00007fcf7f0ba000)
    libxcb.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0x00007fcf7f090000)
    libxcb-render.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-render.so.0 (0x00007fcf7f081000)
    libXrender.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXrender.so.1 (0x00007fcf7ee75000)
    libpcre.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0x00007fcf7ee02000)
    libICE.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libICE.so.6 (0x00007fcf7ede4000)
    libuuid.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuuid.so.1 (0x00007fcf7eddb000)
    libwebp.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwebp.so.6 (0x00007fcf7ed71000)
    libzstd.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libzstd.so.1 (0x00007fcf7ecc6000)
    libjbig.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjbig.so.0 (0x00007fcf7eab8000)
    libatspi.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libatspi.so.0 (0x00007fcf7ea81000)
    libmount.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmount.so.1 (0x00007fcf7ea21000)
    libselinux.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1 (0x00007fcf7e9f6000)
    libresolv.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2 (0x00007fcf7e9d8000)
    libgraphite2.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgraphite2.so.3 (0x00007fcf7e9ab000)
    libgpg-error.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgpg-error.so.0 (0x00007fcf7e988000)
    libdatrie.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdatrie.so.1 (0x00007fcf7e97e000)
    libXau.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0x00007fcf7e976000)
    libXdmcp.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0x00007fcf7e96e000)
    libbsd.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbsd.so.0 (0x00007fcf7e954000)
    libblkid.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libblkid.so.1 (0x00007fcf7e8fd000)
    libpcre2-8.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre2-8.so.0 (0x00007fcf7e86d000)

$ ls -al  ~/.config/filezilla
total 60
drwx------  2 asr asr  4096 Nov 21 20:09 .
drwxr-xr-x 59 asr asr  4096 Nov 21 15:34 ..
-rw-rw-r--  1 asr asr  8437 Nov 21 20:09 filezilla.xml
-rw-rw-r--  1 asr asr   375 Nov 21 19:10 layout.xml
-rw-r--r--  1 asr asr     0 Nov 21 15:34 lockfile
-rw-r--r--  1 asr asr 28672 Nov 21 15:34 queue.sqlite3
-rw-rw-r--  1 asr asr   463 Nov 21 19:11 recentservers.xml
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: It's not `superuser`. Look under `~/.config`.

Comment: I've updated the question after correcting the typo. Perhaps the outputs might help?

Comment: Why are you calling `filezilla` from command line? Can you [edit] your question and paste the output of `ls -al  ~/.config/filezilla`?

Comment: `filezilla` does not open when called from the start menu, so I called it from the command line. I've added the requested output.

Comment: I would run `sudo apt autoclean && sudo apt autoremove && sudo apt update && sudo apt dist-upgrade` to ensure that my system is up-to-date. Then, I would temporarily move FileZilla's config directory and retry: `cd ~/.config ; mv filezilla filezilla.tmp`. Another option is to try with a newly created user.